# Why values are not retrieved from SQLite database when application is restarted

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite

I am working on an android application in which I have to store contacts information. The application stores the contacts and retrieves them correctly unless and until I restart the application. After restarting the application, when I try to retrieve the values the program crashes unexpectedly. If I re-enter the values or insert a new value and then try to retrieve values then all contacts are retrieved including the previous contacts.

Can anybody explain the reason and device a solution for this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Here is the Contacts class:

```
public class Contact {
    //private variables 
    int _id; 
    String _name; 
    String _phone_number; 

    // Empty constructor 
    public Contact(){ 

    } 
    // constructor 
    public Contact(int id, String name, String _phone_number){ 
        this._id = id; 
        this._name = name; 
        this._phone_number = _phone_number; 
    } 

    // constructor 
    public Contact(String name, String _phone_number){ 
        this._name = name; 
        this._phone_number = _phone_number; 
    } 
    // getting ID 
    public int getID(){ 
        return this._id; 
    } 

    // setting id 
    public void setID(int id){ 
        this._id = id; 
    } 

    // getting name 
    public String getName(){ 
        return this._name; 
    } 

    // setting name 
    public void setName(String name){ 
        this._name = name; 
    } 

    // getting phone number 
    public String getPhoneNumber(){ 
        return this._phone_number; 
    } 

    // setting phone number 
    public void setPhoneNumber(String phone_number){ 
        this._phone_number = phone_number; 
    } 
}
```

and here is the database handler class:

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    // Database Version 
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1; 

    // Database Name 
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contactsManager"; 

    // Contacts table name 
    private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "contacts"; 

    // Contacts Table Columns names 
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id"; 
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name"; 
    private static final String KEY_PH_NO = "phone_number"; 

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) { 
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION); 
    } 

    // Creating Tables 
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) { 
        String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT" + ")"; 
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE); 
    } 

    // Upgrading database 
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) { 
        // Drop older table if existed 
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS); 

        // Create tables again 
        onCreate(db); 
    }

    public void addContact(Contact contact) { 
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); 

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues(); 
        values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName()); // Contact Name 
        values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getPhoneNumber()); // Contact Phone Number 

        // Inserting Row 
        db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values); 
        db.close(); // Closing database connection 
    }

    public void delete() { 
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); 
        db.execSQL("delete * from "+ TABLE_CONTACTS); 
        db.close(); // Closing database connection 
    }

    // Getting All Contacts 
    public List<Contact> getAllContacts() { 
       List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>(); 
       // Select All Query 
       String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS; 

       SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); 
       Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null); 

       // looping through all rows and adding to list 
       if (cursor.moveToFirst()) { 
           do { 
               Contact contact = new Contact(); 
               contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0))); 
               contact.setName(cursor.getString(1)); 
               contact.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(2)); 
               // Adding contact to list 
               contactList.add(contact); 
           } while (cursor.moveToNext()); 
       } 

       // return contact list 
       return contactList; 
   }
}
```

and here is the LogCat:

```
    01-13 18:46:36.734: D/dalvikvm(1166): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 70K, 50% free 2692K/5379K, external 1859K/2108K, paused 20ms
    01-13 18:46:38.687: D/AndroidRuntime(1166): Shutting down VM
    01-13 18:46:38.687: W/dalvikvm(1166): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015578)
    01-13 18:46:38.687: E/AndroidRuntime(1166): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    01-13 18:46:38.687: E/AndroidRuntime(1166): java.lang.NullPointerException
    01-13 18:46:38.687: E/AndroidRuntime(1166):     at com.example.tourguide_final.TourGuide$1.onClick(TourGuide.java:75)
    01-13 18:46:38.687: E/AndroidRuntime(1166):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:159)
    01-13 18:46:38.687: E/AndroidRuntime(1166):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    01-13 18:46:38.687: E/AndroidRuntime(1166):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    01-13 18:46:38.687: E/AndroidRuntime(1166):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
    01-13 18:46:38.687: E/AndroidRuntime(1166):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    01-13 18:46:38.687: E/AndroidRuntime(1166):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    01-13 18:46:38.687: E/AndroidRuntime(1166):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
    01-13 18:46:38.687: E/AndroidRuntime(1166):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
    01-13 18:46:38.687: E/AndroidRuntime(1166):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: post code and crash log.

Comment: I have posted the code and error log

Comment: `com.example.tourguide_final.TourGuide$1.onClick(TourGuide.java:75)` can you please direct us to line `75` of the `TourGuide` class?

Comment: Here is the line 75 of class Tour Guide:

List<Contact> contacts = db.getAllContacts();

Answer (score 0):

You have a NPE on TourGuide$1.onClick line 75.  If you are using Eclipse, just double click on this line in the log, and it will take you to the problem line.  From just a visual inspection, you can probably figure out which variable has not been initialized properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
   1.) Remove void delete() method .What it is doing at the end of the program it is deleting data from the database .Whwn you restart your program ,coompiler doesn't get any data and throws exception

2.)OR What you can do after restarting 1st call void delete method then insert method and then at last call select query method
```